# R ggplot How to Show Probability of Two Variables

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a distribution of data that is shown below in image 1.  My goal is to show the likelihood that a variable is below a particular value for both X and for Y. For instance, I'd like to have a good way to show that ~95% of values are below 8000 on X-axis and below 6500 on the Y-axis.  I am confident that there is a simple answer to this.  I apologize if this has been asked many times before.

```
plot1 <- df %>% ggplot(mapping = aes(x = FLUID_TOT)) + stat_ecdf() + theme_bw()
plot2 <- df %>% ggplot(mapping = aes(x = FLUID_TOT, y = y)) + geom_point() + theme_bw()
```

[image: Continuous data in X and Y]

[image: Cumulative distribution of the X variable]

Comment: Please provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) of your data (eg, via `dput(head)`).  Without it, I can only supply a general approach, such as plotting a labelled `geom_hline` with a value of 0.95

Comment: `ggstatsplot` looks to have some useful functions for your purpose https://github.com/IndrajeetPatil/ggstatsplot